# Search module not working when using a template route to display the results page

Tags: search, template-routes

I am having a bit of trouble getting a search results page to display if the template used for results is being supplied via a template route.

My template faq-search is accessed via /resources/faq/search/results

When I try to search I get an invalid action warning.

```
{exp:search:simple_form result_page="resources/faq/search/result" no_result_page="resources/faq/search/no-result"}
```

If I use the following without a template route it works fine.

```
{exp:search:simple_form result_page="resources/faq-search" no_result_page="resources/faq/search/no-result"}
```

Is this an intended feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue, and filed a bug report - including a fix:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20680